# docker ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED http ajax

Tags: angular, rest, docker, docker-compose

I have 3 simple microservices (mysql, apirest, gui) that I start using docker-compose:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  mysql:
  image: mysql/mysql-server:5.6
  container_name: mysql
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - mysql:/var/lib/mysql/data
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  networks:
    - mynetwork
  deploy:
    mode: replicated
    replicas: 1
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypwd
    - MYSQL_USER=myuser
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=myuserpwd
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=my-db
apirest:
  image: .....apirest:latest
  container_name: apirest
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - apirest:/apirest/tmp
  ports:
    - "30000:3000"
  networks:
    - mynetwork
  deploy:
    mode: replicated
    replicas: 2
gui:
  image: ......gui:latest
  container_name: gui
  restart: always
  links:
      - apirest
  ports:
    - "34200:4200"
  networks:
    - mynetwork

networks:
 mynetwork:

volumes:
 apirest:
 mysql:
```

The **mysql** and the **apirest** microservices can communicate without problem (I can connect to my database from **apirest** using **mysql** as hostname.

But I got the following error in the **gui** microservice as soon as I try to perform an http request (angular) using **apirest** as hostname:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

from the **gui** microservice I can ping the **apirest**:

```
docker exec -it gui ping apirest

--- apirest ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.069/0.203/0.338 ms
```

If I use the public server address (http://serverip:30000/api/test) to perform the http request instead of **apirest** there is no problem, the http request succeed.

What am I doing wrong??

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

AJAX request is the browser request  not the server side request  and your browser  is not a part of mynetwork.
To make ajax request (Client browser need to be public domains or map host file with service node port).
You still need to map host file in your browser host machine or use full url with service node port in your gui code.

if you want to avoid using port, proxying is the best way to expose service in my case I am using Nginx

GUI--- ajax req(browser to server req)----> PROXY(NGINX)---(server to server)--> apirest

Comment: Could you show me a basic configuration of NGINX with docker compose?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as mentioned above, the browser request with ajax is not going through because it is not part of the default network for the containers set up by docker-compose.
However, **for development purposes** if you still want the `gui` microservice to communicate with the `apirest` since you have port forwarding for both services in the docker-compose file i.e for gui `34200:4200` and apirest `30000:3000` you can use the bound host ports(on same network) to communicate by having the request url vary depending on where the request comes from.
If the request comes from the apirest container port use the destination url `http://apirest:3000/api/test` while if it comes from the browser(host port) use the url `http://localhost:30000/api/test` that will forward it to `apirest:3000`

A simple implementation of this (*using fetch api):

```
//in the gui microservice
        let host,port;
        if (window.location.host ==="localhost:34200") {
            host="localhost";
            port="30000"
        }else{
            host="apirest";
            port="3000"
        }
    
         
        const data = await fetch(`http://${host}:${port}/api/test`,
                {  
                    method:"GET"
                })
                .then(res =>  res.json())
                .then(..)
```

*I used the same thing and was able to view my dockerized application via the browser on localhost **for development purposes**. I would recommend the use of a proxy above for production.*