# Container alias name not working when trying to run in network for angular http request

Tags: angularjs, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose yml file with 3 service. A spring boot REST service, a mysql service, and an angular app:

```
version: '3'
services:
container-mysql:
    image: mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypassword
    container_name: container-mysql
container-angular-app:
    build: angularjsapp
    ports:
    - '80:80'
    depends_on:
    - container-app
    container_name: container-angular-app
container-app:
    build: ../workspace/ContainerBackendBoot
    depends_on:
    - container-mysql
    ports:
    - '8080:8080'
    container_name: container-app
```

I am able to connect to my mysql instance from my REST service by setting the application.properties db url to be

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://container-mysql:3306/db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

But when I try to call my REST service from angular like so:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://container-app:8080/container'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.greeting = response.data;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
     $scope.greeting = "Failed to connect to backend. Double check your network.";
  });
});
```

I get a GET http://container-app:8080/container net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error in chrome.

Why can I not connect to my REST service from angular with the "container-app" alias?

Comment: should be localhost:8080/yourRoute

Comment: that works fine but what about when pushing to other environments? Wouldn't taking advantage of the alias be better?

Comment: All the examples I have seen access by localhost / whatever host you are on. That's why you are binding the ports: ` - '8080:8080' `

Comment: Based on the docker documentation on networking, you should be able to reference a container by going to <container-name>:<port> much like I did with the mysql running instance

Comment: Check out any number of tutorials on Docker networking if you still don't understand - you can only use the Docker network hostnames from within that network. Your browser is outside the network. If you copy-paste things like `8080:8080` without understanding what it's doing, you are not going to understand.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47551264/docker-err-name-not-resolved-http-ajax

Answer (score 1):

You use angular in front-end side and you open your website in the browser then You cannot access a container name from the browser.

you must use container name when you want to mention that in another container. for example when you want to use a Redis container in you another app container.

In a front-end side, you must use IP and port exposed in your app.

Answer (score 0):

u are missing the links on the docker-compose.yml

need to add something like this

links:
      - container-app

Comment: docker compose has a default network they are all connecting to. Also links are deprecated. They work through network fine. Its just one of the services that isn't connecting